# Does 'opine' have condescending connotations in the context, or is this purely my own subjective reading?

Tags: meaning, word-choice

I need to know if 'opines' here sounds condescending. In my ears it does, but it may be my individual reading and not objective. To me it sounds like a somewhat old fashioned word, which gives me a feeling that it is being used ironically and in the context somewhat condescendingly. I distrust my instinct so am looking to see what others think.

Here is the passage:

> A philosopher, Origen opines, affiliates with a “sect [ai[resij]” only
>   “because he believes his particular sect to be superior to any other”
>   (1,10). Origen’s pragmatic arguments for a faith without reason are
>   not much more convincing than his understanding of philosophy, which
>   comes across as a caricature of cluelessness.

The background is a book I am translating. The author himself has already done a lot of work on quotations looking for the corresponding English citations in authorised translations. In such cases he gives the citations in English *including some other English words surrounding the citations*.
 When incorporating the citations into my translation I have a certain license to change the surrounding words as long as the citations are kept intact. The first sentence in the passage above is his and I am wondering whether I would be justified in suggesting 'claims' rather than 'opines' (because I think he weakens his own argument by sounding unnecessarily snide; the argument should stand for itself).

Comment: To opine means to express one’s opinion about something or someone. Whether it may sound condescending on this specific case  is really a matter of personal opinion.

Comment: You may be right. For some reason 'claims' sounded more neutral in my ears. But perhaps that is just me.

Comment: You are translating a book *about* Origen's work? About a translation from the ancient Greek? When was the critique written, and the translation?

Comment: No. I'm translating a German book (on the interactions between the Christians and the pagans in the late antique and how the pagan writings later influenced early modern and Enlightenment thinkers).  'Opine' here is just a verb.

Comment: That was a typo, corrected.

Comment: If you are translating a German book why does it contain "opine"?

Comment: I tried to explain that in the question: The author himself has already done a lot of work on quotations looking for the corresponding English citations in authorised translations. In such cases he gives the citations in English including some other English words surrounding the citations.

Comment: You could be right, because the quotation puts down Origen’s understanding of faith and philosophy. I have not read or heard the word "opine" in decades, so perhaps its use *is* an allusion to Origen's supposed lack of understanding. However it is subjective: perhaps the lack is in the mind of the author you are translating.

Comment: I find ***claims*** to have more undertone than *opines*.

Comment: 'opine' is in a very hoity-toity register, very purple prosish. So that may contribute to your feelings that something is condescending here, whether it is the author, translator, or the subject himself, Origen. My reading is I don't think the word is condescending to Origen, it literally is saying that Origen is giving an opinion.

Comment: @Mitch. I think that's it. I may suggest he change to 'claims', but also note that it's a very personal opinion.

Comment: @Jim. Interesting. It's starting to feel very much like my own subjective opinion.

Comment: Perhaps, but it is only foreshadowing the tone of the quote. The quote is a tad heavy-handed by itself. It seems like an apt label that is setting the context for the following text.

Comment: If you look at google ngram for "opines that" you will find pretty steady growth in its frequency. I find that astonishing because I would regard it as such an odd  - and old-fashioned - word to use where there are more familiar synonyms that using it is making some kind of statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to **opine** [vocabulary.com](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/opine)

> express one's opinion openly and without fear or hesitation

My sense is that opine does not have condescending connotations.  Of course its use in context could.  It's synonym to 'sound off' can more likely have such connotations.

A couple of recent sentences with usage:

> I hesitate to even opine, especially on the controversial subject of
>   An Alternate Form of Movie Popcorn. Seattle Times 2018

and

> That looks like cheap plastic veneer over chipboard in the Arsenal
>   dressing room,” opines Bruce Jackson. The Guardian 2018

and

> But on social media, many opined that nothing fits the definition
>   better than the tuxedo-drenched bash. Fox News 2018

Comment: OP does know the meaning of **opine**. How does this answer the question? The question is more subtle than dictionary references.

Comment: @WeatherVane The meaning of *opine* may be known—but that's never stated in the question, The question doesn't provide a definition, nor any explanation for *why* it might be interpreted as condescending. Based on the lack of detail in the question, this is an appropriate answer.

Comment: @Jason Bassford. So you opine that I should have done more research? Fair point. The problem was/is I wasn't sure why it felt condescending and whether there was an objective reason for this, or if it was just me. I'm beginning to think because the word is somewhat unusual it draws unnecessary attention to itself and makes one wonder why the author chose that particular word. In any case the comments have been helpful.